# Task Does not Update UI in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I wrote this code:

```
public double SumRootN(int root)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        result += Math.Exp(Math.Log(i) / root);
    }
    return result;
}

private void btnclick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    txttest.Text = "";

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    for (int i = 2; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        var compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return SumRootN(j);
        }, tokenSource.Token);

        tasks.Add(compute);

        var displayResults = compute.ContinueWith(
                                resultTask =>
                                   txttest.Text
                                    += "root " + j.ToString() + " " +
                                        compute.Result.ToString() +
                                        Environment.NewLine,
                                CancellationToken.None,
                                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                                ui);             
    }      
}
```

It works in WPF but when I wrote this code this way;

```
tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Report 
   += ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)_sheet.Cells[row, "B"]).Value2;

var compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {
                return Report;                             
             }, tokenSource.Token);

            tasks.Add(compute);

            var displayResults
                = compute.ContinueWith(resultTask =>
                     txtReport.Text 
                        += compute.Result.ToString() +
                           Environment.NewLine,
                     CancellationToken.None,
                     TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                     ui);
```

It does not work, whereas `txtReport.Text` has correct values, but it does not show in the middle of operation but when operation ends `txtReport` show it's values

Why does this code not work?

Comment: Does your view model implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: You still need to tell the XAML that the property has changed.

Comment: please describe me a little more...

Comment: @ChrisF: I don't see here a missing INPC. The OP sets txttest.Text directly. There is no need for the PropertyChanged-event. Am I wrong?

Comment: @HCL - Ah - I see your point. My comments above are wrong - I misunderstood what property was being updated.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `computed` task in your second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContinueWith` creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes. I.e it will only update the result once your `SumRootN` operation complete.

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with TaskScheduler, therefore I can not give you a direct feedback whats wrong. But from your problem description, I'm quite shure that the problem is that the UI-thread is blocked. As long as your code has not terminated, the UI will not be updated.

For time time consuming operations, do them with a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). However take care that you can not set values of your controls from within the asynchronous directly. Either use the Dispatcher to route your command to the UI-thread or use the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx)-event.

The following code shows you how to use the BackgroundWorker:

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress=true};  
bgWorker.DoWork += (s, e) => {      
    // Do here your calculations
    // Use bgWorker.ReportProgress(); to report the current progress  
};  
bgWorker.ProgressChanged+=(s,e)=>{      
    // Here you will be informed about progress and here it is save to set the labels value. 
};  
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => {      
// Here you will be informed if the job is done. 
};  
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: but I use a code like that in winforms and it works. use 1`var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(); ' for synch threads.why that does not work?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few troubleshooting tips for this... You may have to answer these questions first...

1. Where is your code actually located? In Button_click() call?
2. When you put brekapoint on your code `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();` what kind of `SynchronizationContext` object do you see? `Dispatcher` type? Or some other type?
3. Is there a specific reason to use TPL? Cant you use `BackgroundWorker` and `Dispatcher` pair?